# Avoiding taxes on backdoor Roth IRA conversion

Tags: united-states, 401k, roth-ira, roth-conversion

I have 4 accounts:

- Vanguard traditional IRA with ~$90k in it
- Vanguard Roth IRA ~$25k in it
- Vanguard 401k from a *former* employer that has ~$40k in it
- Mass Mutual 401k from *current* employer that has ~30k in it

I’ve already contributed $5,500 to the Roth IRA for 2017, but due to some unexpectedly large bonuses at work, I am over the income limit for directly contributing to a Roth.

What’s the best way for me to keep that $5,500 as a Roth contribution and also allow myself to make future Roth IRA contributions?

What I was thinking is:

1. Roll my Vanguard traditional IRA into my current 401k
2. Call Vanguard and recharacterize my 2017 Roth contributions as post-tax non-deductible traditional IRA contributions
3. Backdoor convert that traditional IRA into the Roth IRA

Is this possible? I know you can’t co-mingle pre and post-tax traditional IRA contributions and then backdoor Roth without a tax penalty, but will draining that account by rolling it into my 401k before recharacterizing the current year’s Roth contribution avoid that?

Comment: Can you max-out your 401(k) so you're below the Roth contribution threshold?

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Already done fortunately/unfortunately :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the textbook way to avoid *pro rata* taxes when doing a backdoor Roth IRA. I will note that you could technically even reverse steps 1 and 2/3, as taxes on an IRA conversion are determined by your IRA balances on December 31 of that year (see [Form 8606 - Nondeductible IRAs](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-8606) for details). And the sooner you do the conversion, the less gains there will be to pay regular income tax on. Just be sure you finish the IRA->401(k) roll-in by the end of the year.

Another thing to consider. It may be possible to roll-in your IRA balance into your old Vanguard 401(k) instead of your current Mass Mutual 401(k). In general, the former will have lower fees and better fund choices.

Comment: That 12/31 effective date is super important.  You can mix before-tax and after-tax money all you want until then.  Conversely, if you only notice the problem *after* January 1 (as I once did), things get a lot more complicated. :(

Comment: "I will note that you could technically even reverse steps 1 and 2/3" I think there will be issues if you do step 3 before 1, because rollovers from Traditional IRA to 401(k) can only contain pre-tax amounts. If your conversion from Traditional IRA to Roth IRA contained some pre-tax and some after-tax amounts, according to the pro-rata rule, then that will subtract from the pre-tax amount in the Traditional IRA that you can rollover to 401(k). So if you try to rollover to 401(k) what you thought was the whole pre-tax amount, that will be an illegal rollover.

Comment: However, I think step 2 *should* be done before step 1, ideally, because if there are earnings in the Roth-recharacterized-as-Traditional IRA, they would be pre-tax and should be rolled over into 401(k) too to avoid any taxes in the conversion.

Comment: @user102008 By "steps 2/3" I meant to convey that this pair of steps has to be done in that order. So no, you couldn't do step 3 then 1, but you could do steps 2, 3, then 1, in addition to 1, 2, then 3. And I agree, the 2, 3, 1 order is preferable, as long as one is sure they will get the IRA->401(k) roll-in done before the end of the year.

Comment: @CraigW: I was saying that I am not sure about 2, 3, 1, because it depends on how the rule about only pre-tax amounts being able to be rolled into 401(k) works. When is the amount of pre-tax money available to roll over determined? If the conversion immediately changes the amount of pre-tax/post-tax in the Traditional IRA, and if the determination for the rollover to 401(k) is made after that, then it wouldn't work because the conversion would have already decreased the amount of pre-tax money in the Traditional IRA.

Comment: @CraigW: In order for it to work the way you suggest, it seems that they would have to somehow determine the amount of pre-tax money available to rollover to 401(k) as of the state before any conversions were made, which seems weird to me.

Comment: @user102008 Not sure I follow. Let's say the recharacterization comes out to $6000 ($5500 contribution plus some earnings; brokerage calculates this) and it gets moved into their Traditional IRA. They immediately convert $6000. It goes back into the Roth IRA. $500 is taxed like regular income. Whatever is left in the Traditional IRA is all pre-tax and can be rolled-in to the 401(k).

Comment: @CraigW: Conversion takes out money from Traditional IRA pro-rata. If they did the conversion with some pre-tax and some after-tax money in Traditional IRA, it would contain partly pre-tax and partly after-tax money, and it would leave some pre-tax and some after-tax money in the Traditional IRA after conversion. If the rollover to 401(k) is considered to have happened "after" the conversion, it would not be able to rollover the full amount left, because some of it is pre-tax and some of it is after-tax.

Comment: @CraigW: I think what you are trying to say only makes sense if the rollover to 401(k) is considered to have happened "before" the conversion, for the purposes of determining how much is allowed to rollover to 401(k), but I am not sure if that's how it works.

Comment: @user102008 Think I follow you now. The conversion does take money out of the Traditional IRA pro rata, but the proportions are determined by the end of year balances, as per Form 8606. Hence I believe one could do steps 2, 3, 1. That being said, if I were in this situation I would likely just do 1, 2, 3 to be safe.

Comment: @user102008 And in my example of $6000 being recharacterized, I believe you could even convert only $5500 and include the $500 of earnings with your roll-in.

Comment: @CraigW: But your "end of the year balance" depends on the rollover to 401(k) taking the money out of the Traditional IRA, which depends on the rollover being legal, which it only is if it's all pre-tax money, therefore my question about how the amount of pre-tax money available to be rolled over to 401(k) is determined.

Comment: @user102008 Your after-tax basis is always going to be $5500. So as long as you convert at least that much, the rest must be pre-tax and is all legit to be rolled-in to a 401(k).